# How to get the parameter list inside the stored procedure itself

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I know it's easy to get outside like:

```
select * from sys.parameters
where object_id in 
      (select object_id from sys.procedures where name = 'YourSProc')
```

But if I have a SP which has optional parameter with default value, how can I know whether a parameter is actually being set if the param value==param default value?

like

```
create procedure sp1
@userid=1,
@passwd=null,
as
bla..bla
Go
```

In the stored procedure itself, how can I know whether user called

```
exec sp1 @userid=1, @passwd=null
```

or

```
exec sp2 @userid=2
```

Is there a global variable like @@paramlist which can provide the parameter list?

Comment: You can't easily (if at all). Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @JeffO, I'm using MSSQL.

Comment: @MartinSmith, if I set the default value of an optional parameter to null, then I add some logic to check if it's null, if it's not I will avoid some updating work. But what if I do it this way, I can't handle when the optional parameter is passed in as null.

Comment: So you mean something like `UPDATE Foo SET Bar=@Bar, Baz=@Baz` where columns `Bar` and `Baz` could both potentially be updated to `NULL` and if neither were passed in at all you would just skip that Update as not being passed in would indicate "leave unchanged" rather than "set to NULL"? If so can't think of a good way of doing that. Extra parameters possibly.

Comment: @MartinSmith, just like you say. I will try providing extra parameter.

Comment: @MartinSmith, we seem to be in the odd situation where Orange likes your suggestion, but has accepted my answer.  I like rep points as much as the next guy, but perhaps you should post your comment as an answer so that Orange can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite what you are looking for, but what if instead of defaulting to null, you set the default to some unlikely and secret sentinel value - perhaps a GUID.  Then you would check in your SP if the parameter was set to the GUID, which would mean that the parameter was defaulted, or set to anything else, in which case the user supplied it.

Comment: this is probably fine for some fields. How can I set a secret sentinel value for a nullable bool?

Comment: Therein lies the weakness of my approach.  I like @Martin Smith's suggestion better honestly.

Comment: Thank you guys. I think @MartinSmith's solution's good for me.